# Some questions about bootable USB's

Tags: usb

I'm planning on making a bootable USB, but first I have some questions regarding it, you can answer any of the questions you like.

- Can a bootable USB access a hard drive where windows is installed on without password?
- What is the safest OS for a bootable USB?
- Which OS is the freeest (as in editing the source code and such)

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create and boot the system from a USB is not much different from normal one, the only difference is in kernel, on hardware abstraction layer (this is handled by OS) and data transfer speed.

1. Yes, as long as the OS from USB have SATA (or whatever you have) driver and accept your HDD partitions format (NTFS/EXT etc). It doesn't matter if you have or not password but to have the data unencrypted. (usually user personal's folders are encrypted).
2. Safest.. no one is safer than another.
3. Mainly any Linux distribution.

I will recommend Ubuntu because it have the biggest community.